# Can Mathematica solve this second-order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x^2 g'' + \frac{\nu x^2 g'^2}{\eta^2} + \frac{(\alpha\eta+2\nu) x g'}{\eta} - \beta g + \nu = 0\ ,
$$
where the Greek letters are constants. I have so far only managed to locate the steady-state solution $g(x) = \nu  /\beta$. Due to a broken laptop, I'm currently forced to use Wolfram Cloud, where the computation times out. So my question: is Mathematica in fact able to solve this ODE? If not, I would be grateful for any other solution ideas/hints, e.g. in terms of implicit functions.

The code is the following:

```
pdeg = \[Beta] g[x] == \[Nu] + (x (\[Alpha] \[Eta]+2 \[Nu]) g'[x])/\[Eta] + (x^2 \[Nu] g'[x]^2)/\[Eta]^2 + 1/2 x^2 \[Sigma]^2 g''[x]

DSolve[pdeg, g, x]
```

Comment: It does not seem to be solvable., Even with numerical values for the parameters. Mathematica can't solve and neither can Maple. So it looks like lost case. Try numerical solution or series solution. It is because of the $(g')^2$ term in there.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for running the code! Would you be able to explain how to construct a series solution in Mathematica, or provide a reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony What is known about the x-range? `0<x<Infinity`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, that is correct, $0 < x < \infty$. For my application, I am interested in $x$ rather large, say $\mathcal{O}(10^4)$.

Comment: It might be of interest to note that Mathematica can solve the equation analytically when $\beta = 0$.  In this case, the solution generally has a logarithmic singularity as $x \to 0$, and diverges proportionally to $\ln x$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: What else is known, initial or boundary conditions?

Comment: FWIW, $x=e^t$ transforms the ODE into an autonomous form, whose contact field is thus on a surface in ${\Bbb R}^3$ and can be visualized for numerical settings of the parameters.

Comment: @yarchik Well, this is actually part of a system of three ODEs that I need to stitch together, very similar to a one-dimensional free-boundary problem. So for instance, I know that for some to-be-determined $x_a$ > 0, it must satisfy $g(x_a) = f(x_a)$ and $g'(x_a) = f'(x_a)$ where $f(x) = C_1 x^m$, where $m > 1$ depends on the constants in the problem. So at this boundary, I will have to solve for $x_a$ and $C_1$. Then I play a similar game on the left boundary, at some $x_b > x_a$. But this seemed too much for the question - I can make this computations if I know the general solution.

Comment: @Goofy that sounds most interesting in light of the comment I just made regarding the free-boundary problem I am trying to solve. Would you care to elaborate on your comment in an answer, or provide a reference? I'm not too familiar with autonomous forms.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you for pointing this out--that's really helpful. I wonder if there might be a way to exploit this information to perturb the equation around $\beta = 0$? I am interested in any case in the regime $0 < \beta < 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To illustrate my comment about $x=e^t$ turning the ODE into an autonomous one. Autonomous just means the coefficients are constants or equivalently the vector field $dY/dt = F(Y)$ is time-independent. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autonomous.html, for instance. It reduces the dimension of the system by 1. In a second-order ODE, the reduction permits the visualization of phase portrait (2D) or the contact manifold (surface in 3D).

Phase portrait example (note `g[x] = h[Log[x]]`):

```
hode = DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][pdeg, g, x], h, t, 
     x == Exp[t]] // First // Simplify;
With[{hA = -3, hB = 5, hpA = -4, hpB = 2,
  hpp = First@SolveValues[hode, h''[t]]},
 Manipulate[
  StreamPlot[{h'[t], hpp}, {h[t], hA, hB}, {h'[t], hpA, hpB},
   Epilog -> {RGBColor[0, 0.8, 0.6], PointSize@Large, 
     Point[{\[Nu]/\[Beta], 0}]}],
  {{\[Alpha], 1}, 0, 2}, {{\[Beta], 1}, 0, 2}, {{\[Eta], 1}, 0, 2},
  {{\[Nu], 1}, 0 + $MachineEpsilon, 2}, {{\[Sigma], 1}, 0, 2},
  TrackedSymbols :> {\[Beta], \[Nu], \[Alpha], \[Sigma], \[Eta]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Note on symmetry: In an autonomous ODE, if $h_1$ is a solution, then so is $h_1(t+C)$ for any constant $C$. Correspondingly, under the substitution $x=e^t$, if $g_1$ is a solution to the OP's ODE, then so is $g_1(C\,x)$ (for $C \ne 0$).

Comment: Clever idea `x->Exp[t]`. But unfortunately the stationary point doesn't look stable. Perhaps that might be the reason why series solution can't be derived?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks, but why "unfortunately"? Shouldn't we say fortunately we are able to determine the stability of the stationary point? In fact, the determinant of the Jacobian is a constant $-{2 \beta }/{\sigma^2}$. Of course, with different parameter settings, we can get stationary points of different types — but not for $0 < \beta < 1$, which is the range that the OP is interested in. It's a saddle if $\beta$ is positive.

Answer (score 9):

> how to construct a series solution,

It can solve it by series, but expansion point can not be zero. (the reason is, at $x=0$ the whole ode goes away, and you end up with the equation

```
 β  g[0] == ν
```

Here is your ode

```
pdeg=β g[x]==ν+(x (α η+2 ν) g'[x])/η+(x^2 ν g'[x]^2)/η^2+1/2 x^2 σ^2 g''[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[pdeg, g[x], {x, 0, 4}]
(*no solution*)
```

but using 4 terms, the solution around $x=1$ is

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[pdeg, g[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]